# AFNetworking - 401 response from https server (login action)

Tags: ios, https, afnetworking

I know that this problem may be api specified but really need to try. 
I have to requests. One made with ASIHTTP and the other one with AFNetworking. Server denies afnetworking with 401 code.

I have to adjust afnetworking to the working state, and have in mind that changes at the server side are impossible atm.

**ASIHTTP (working one)**

```
POST https://cant.post.address HTTP/1.1
Host: cant.post.address
Accept: application/json
User-Agent: My Application(iPhone; iPhone OS 6.1.3; pl_PL)
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=utf-8
Accept-Encoding: gzip
Connection: close
Proxy-Connection: close
Content-Length: 31
```

**AFNETWORKING (getting denied with 401)**

```
POST https://cant.post.address HTTP/1.1
Host: cant.post.address
Accept: application/json
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
User-Agent: MyApp(iPhone; iOS 6.1.3; Scale/2.00)
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=utf-8
Accept-Language: pl;q=1, en;q=0.9, fr;q=0.8, de;q=0.7, ja;q=0.6, nl;q=0.5
Connection: keep-alive
Proxy-Connection: keep-alive
Content-Length: 31
```

There were some other headers but they were identical so I removed for simplicity. What could cause rejecting here? user-agent? Doubt that. What about Connection and Proxy-Connection? Can i change it to close in AFN?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

401 is the HTTP status code "Unauthorized", which is sent back from the server when the provided credentials are invalid (incorrect username / password). Check that you're sending the correct information.

Also, JSON serialization is provided automatically when `AFHTTPClient` is configured correctly. See the example app in the AFNetworking repository to see how that is done.

Comment: It's probably a cookie or stale session, then. Try resetting the simulator and trying again.